# Error while displaying data from MySql using bash script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell

Here I have a database msmdb  which contains a table emp.
I am trying to display the values in that table using a bash script but there comes an error saying command not found (at line 8 after the echo).

```
USER_NAME=root    
USER_PWD=prj    
DB_NAME=msmdb

flag=0     
delimiter="a3f4g52"

echo "select id ,'"$delimiter"', name,'"$delimiter"', city, '"$delimiter"', salary FROM emp" | \ 

mysql -u $USER_NAME --password=$USER_PWD --database=$DB_NAME | \ 

while read row ; 
do

   if [ $flag == 0 ]; then 
      flag=1 

   else 
      name=` echo $row | \ 
             awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $1}' | \ 
             sed -e 's/ *$//' | sed 's/^ *//'` 

      age=` echo $row | \ 
            awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $2}' | \ 
            sed -e 's/ *$//' | sed 's/^ *//'` 

      bornPlace=`echo $row | \ 
                 awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $3}' | \ 
                 sed -e 's/ *$//' | sed 's/^ *//'` 

      echo ">$name<"
      echo ">$age<"
      echo ">$bornPlace<"

   fi 
done
```

Any idea about what might be the reason for error ??

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you you also include a line in your script which does `echo $PATH`, and show the output in your post? Also can you post the location of your `mysql` binary (the output of `which mysql` from the shell)?

This information would confirm what I suspect is the problem: that `mysql` isn't in the path of the script being executed. There are a couple of solutions, but one would be: instead of writing `mysql <args>`, put the full path to the mysql binary: `/usr/local/bin/mysql` (or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got The Script working properly ......

Just had to remove ' \ ' from the program and it worked.

The Correct bash script is

```
USER_NAME=root 
USER_PWD=prj
DB_NAME=msmdb 
flag=0 
delimiter="a3f4g52" 

echo "select id ,'"$delimiter"', name,'"$delimiter"', city, '"$delimiter"', salary FROM emp" |
mysql -u $USER_NAME --password=$USER_PWD --database=$DB_NAME |  

while read row ; 
do 
   if [ $flag == 0 ]; then 
      flag=1 
else 
      name=` echo $row | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/ *$//' | sed 's/^ *//'` 
      age=` echo $row | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/ *$//' | sed 's/^ *//'` 
      bornPlace=` echo $row | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/ *$//' | sed 's/^ *//'` 

   echo ">$name<" 
   echo ">$age<" 
   echo ">$bornPlace<" 
fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 8 you have a space following the linebreak (\) therefore the linebreak doesn't work.

Comment: Well got the script working right. The space was not the problem the '\' (linebreak) itself was giving the problem. I removed it from my script and it executed properly.